# How do you run a python script from within Eclipse PyDev using -m flag

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

My python script is executed via the -m flag:

```
python -m MyPythonModule.MyPhythonModule command_line_arg1 command_line_arg2
```

However, I can't seem to get to this to work in Eclipse PyDev using the run configuration. Using that tool, it seems I always need to specify a .py file to run. Is there a way I can configure the run configuration tool to run my script with the -m flag similar to the above?

Comment: were u able to add the arguments? then adding a flag is similar

Comment: @Konstant Yes, I can add arguments but the problem is that Eclipse is expecting a script to be run. With -m, no script is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible at this time.